# Using PagedList.Mvc for partial page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I have four different tabs in one page and data for each tab is rendered by an ajax call using partial page. Data for tab is loaded by ajax post.
 ajax call:

```
  $('#movieDatabase').click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'html',
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Admin/GetMovieDatabase',
                data: {},
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#view16').html(data);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert('error');
                    $('#view16').html(response);
                }
            });
        });
```

This ajax call rendered the partial page. Now I want to do is paging the movie came from database.For this I use PagedList.Mvc. But problem occurred in navigating movie from one page to another. It is done by:

```
 @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.MovieInforamtions, page => Url.Action("GetMovieDatabase", new { page }))
```

But when I click on next page it gives page not found error as I have not written any action in HTTPGet. And If I made above call by HTTPGet, I couldnot render all page but only partial page. My action is..

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult GetMovieDatabase(int? page)
 {
      var AdminGetMovieDatabaseViewModel = new AdminGetMovieDatabaseViewModel();
      var allMovie = _AdminService.getAllMovieInfo();
      var pageNumber = page ?? 1; 
      // if no page was specified in the querystring, default to the first page (1)
      var onePageOfMovie = allMovie.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 5); 
      // will only contain 5 products max because of the pageSize

      AdminGetMovieDatabaseViewModel.MovieInforamtions = onePageOfMovie;

      return PartialView("MovieDataBasePartialPage", AdminGetMovieDatabaseViewModel);
   }
```

Now How can I render the next page like in ajax call which is done previously?

Answer (score 0):

I put the code in javascript section inside the partial view and works for me.

```
<script language ="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$('#movieDatabase').click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'html',
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Admin/GetMovieDatabase',
                data: {},
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#view16').html(data);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert('error');
                    $('#view16').html(response);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```